# Django Many-to-many change in model save method does not work

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

## Concept

First of all i have a pretty komplex model... The idea is of building a Starship as model. So every Ship has a type(`ship_type`) which is based on a Blueprint of this Shiptype. So when u're creating a Ship u have to decide which `ship_type` the model should use (foreign key).

Because I want to change a ship (example: buy another software) but not the blueprint itself, every Ship has the same fields in the database as the Blueprint Ship (both inherit from `ShipField` ). When someone set the `ship_type` or change it, I want Django to go to the blueprint get all informations and overwrite the information of the ship. So I tried to accomplish this behavior in the save method.

### Function and error search

The function I wrote is always triggerd when there was a change in `self.ship_type`, so far so good. And all "normal" fields are changed too, only the many to many fields don't work.

I dove into it and got confused. Let us assume our ship has no entries in `self.software` but the new `ship_type` has 3. If I print out the `self.software` before the save (1.), I got as expected an empty queryset. When I do it after the super.save (2.) I got a queryset of three elements. So it seems to work everything. But if I take a look at the ship in the admin menu, the ship has no software at all.

### Conclusion

So my conclusion is that somewhere after the save method (perhaps in the post_save event) the software get deleted again... At this point I need some help.

### Ideas

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do here. I am not a database expert and can imagine that there are better ways to achieve this so I'm open for radical changes.

## Models (simplified):

```
class ShipFields(models.Model):
    body = models.ForeignKey(to=Body, verbose_name="Body", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                         null=True, blank=False, default=None)
    software = models.ManyToManyField(Software, default=None, blank=True)
    ...

class ShipBlueprints(ShipFields, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Ship Blueprint"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ship Blueprints"

class Ship(ShipFields, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    ship_type = models.ForeignKey(to=ShipBlueprints, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ...
    __original_ship_type = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ship, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_ship_type = self.ship_type

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if the ship type is changed
        if self.ship_type != self.__original_ship_type:
            ...
            # copy all fields from the related ShipBlueprints to the fields of Ship
            # 1. 
            print(self.software.all())
            self.body = self.ship_type.body
            self.software.set(self.ship_type.software.all())
            # or
            # for soft in self.ship_type.software.all():
            #     self.software.add(soft)
            # 2. 
            print(self.software.all())
            ...
        super(Ship, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        # 2. 
        print(self.software.all())
        print(Ship.objects.get(name=self.name).software.all())
        self.__original_ship_type = self.ship_type
```

I think i narrowed the problem down. When i change the ship_type via admin side, the many_to_many_fields dont get updated. **BUT when i change the ship_type via the django shell it works perfectly!**

When im using a form in a view it works, too. So my code works justfine but the admin page is somehow the problem... For me that's ok but it looks like an error in the saving method of admin, perhaps i will report this.

Thank you all for the ideas.

Comment: I think the problem is maybe you are not calling `save()`  after adding the software set(). So what I think might be happening is that the self.software is being updated in memory but not on the Database. That's why you see it on the prints and not on the django admin. Try searching for the  `.add() ` method in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

If it helps you let me know so I can put this as an answer.

Comment: first thank you for the tip. I tried add before : `[selft.software.add(soft) in selft.ship_type.software.all()]` but at the end its the same.`save()` So u want to say i have to save the software first and than add it? When i have to save them? And there defintly exsísting before in the database in the Software Model

Comment: i tryed this now: `self.software.save()` (after `set()`) but im getting an error:  'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I believe it's because of __original_ship_type. It needs to be a foreign key to ShipBlueprints too. The __original_ship_type won't save anything inside of each row since it's not a database attribute/column. The __original_ship_type is simply part of the **model** for a database record.

That's actually one option. The other option is to use Django signals, specifically, pre_save. When you use pre_save, you are getting the NEW instance and you use this NEW instance's ID to do a DB query for the old instance. Afterwards, you save the object like that. The `pre_save` signal does not necessarily mean you HAVE to save something in there. It's just a signal calling a function.

Comment: I tested it with the pre_save signal its the same error. Just to be shure i deleted __original_ship_type and tryed again(now its overwrting always), but it dosen't help.